# asynchronous message from server through Faye websocket

Tags: ruby, rack, faye

I have successfully implemented a server using Faye websocket library on top of Rack, with a puma webserver, as described [here](http://pythonhackers.com/p/faye/faye-websocket-ruby).

In my application the client first sends audio data to be processed to the server and then iteratively asks the server whether the data has been finished processing. Once the server gets the data it stores it into a queue for processing. Every time the app asks the server, the server checks the queue and either returns null or returns the processed result.

I would like to reimplement this so that the server would asynchronously send a message to the client whenever it finished processing without the client having to iteratively ask all the time.

I have seen possible solutions like sleeping and iteratively checking the status until it is ready, but I am worried this would block the server and would make this not scalable. Another alternative would be using the ping/pong capability of Faye websockets, but I can see this as doing exactly the same I do now.

Any other ideas on how I could implement it?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. You need to research and try things, and then ask a specific question about a particular problem with the code. Asking us for alternative methods results in broad answers, instead of detailed and specific ones.

Comment: @theTinMan hmmm... I am not sure I understand your comment. I have seen many many questions without code in them and a much scarcer description of the problem. In my question I am clearly stating my problem and listing two ways I tried to implement. Please let me know what exactly I could do differently and I will modify my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @XAnguera , the question is too broad without knowing what your code is doing, what you tried and where you're stuck. Your question lacks some information. For example, is the audio data processing performed by the server process or a worker process (perhaps on a different machine)...?  Are you using background processing? Are you using a pub/sub service? ... If the server doubles as the audio processing unit, it will naturally have more information about the progress and the client and it could divide it's work into chunks, increasing responsiveness - but it will have load balancing issues...